# Failed to build substrate-node-template using Macbook pro M1 pro

Tags: substrate-node-template, rust

I'm unable to build substrate-node-template using my Macbook pro M1 Pro laptop.

I updated cmake and followed the [official guide](https://docs.substrate.io/quick-start/)

I also tried with the flag `--locked`

Here is the error log:

```
error: failed to run custom build command for `libp2p-kad v0.41.0
error: failed to run custom build command for `libp2p-identify v0.40.0`
error: failed to run custom build command for `sc-network-light v0.10.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.32#5ea6d953)`
```

---

**Update:**

After following the the [MacOs installation steps](https://docs.substrate.io/install/macos)

1. Updated BREW
2. Installed CMAKE
3. Installed openSSL
4. `rustup default stable` and `rustup update`
5. `rustup update nightly` and `rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown --toolchain nightly`
6. `git clone https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template`
7. `cd substrate-node-template`
8. `cargo build --release` and tried `cargo build --locked`

And now I'm getting the following error:

```
error: failed to run custom build command for `libp2p-core v0.37.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it:

```sh
brew install protobuf
```

fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I just went through the instructions documented here:

- https://docs.substrate.io/quick-start

And it works fine for my M1 Pro.

My CMake version is 3.24.2. What is yours?

Make sure you have the proper recommended setup:

- https://docs.substrate.io/install/macos

Additionally you may want to run:

```sh
xcode-select --install
```

If you are still running into issues, please post the exact steps you went through so we can try to reproduce your issue. And also include the result of running the following commands:

```sh
rustup show
```

```sh
rustup +nightly show
```

Comment: Hey, now im getting the following error ```error: failed to run custom build command for `libp2p-core v0.37.0`}```

Comment: Please update your post with the exact steps you went through so I can try to reproduce your issue. Also include your `rustup show` and `rustup +nightly show`. And the version of CMake that you are using.

Comment: Hey, just i've updated the question.